# How to convert space bar key event in unity into touch event in android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

```
  using UnityEngine;
  public class Player : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // The force which is added when the player jumps
        // This can be changed in the Inspector window
        public Vector2 jumpForce = new Vector2(0, 300);
        // Update is called once per frame
            void Update ()
            {
                // Jump`enter code here
                if (Input.GetKeyUp("space")) /*This is written for spacebar event so how can make it a touch event and to use in it android project */
                {
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero; GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpForce);//It all works fine
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a simple press anywhere on the screen, this should do it.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
   GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero; 
   GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpForce);
}
```

OR

```
if ((Input.touchCount > 0) && (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began))
{
   GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero; 
   GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpForce);
}
```

If you are looking for Button UI on the screen, [learn](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) the Unity UI System.

Comment: Thank for your great help it works now it just a simple plane game when touch it will go up when i release it will come down thanks for your help mate

Comment: @GBGolden You are welcome. Please accept the answer if this solved your problem. http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: done, im new to stack over flow  so i dont know how things work

Comment: @GBGolden . That's fine. I think you know now.

Comment: Hei do u know how to add custom intro splash screen? can i use custom made videos? and how can i convert a video into unity asset?

Comment: @GBGolden You are suppose to new questions since this has nothing to do with this question. To add custom splash screen , disable the original unity splash screen then create a scene with your splash screen. Write a code that waits for some time after displaying the splash screen then load your main scene. To play video on iOS or Android, use the `Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie` class. You can google all these and find answers. How to convert object to Asset in Unity...How to play video in unity?